# How can I use ContentResolver query two Uris' data?

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

I know there are two uris, which are images and thumbnails table in external.db.

**MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI**

**MediaStore.Images.Media.Thumbnail**

This db file is in package com.android.provider.media. We must use ContentResolver to query data.

Now, I want to get _data in images and _data in thumbnails by calling contentResolver.query once.

It that possible?

Comment: so call `ContentResolver#query()` twice

Comment: @pskink what about efficiency?